# Issue with UNCLAIMED video card on Ubuntu Server 22.04.3

Tags: server, nvidia, 22.04, video, gpu

I have 8 NVIDIA Tesla V100 GPUs. Server hardware does recognize all 8 without a problem. They all have identical firmware and identical config in BIOS. However when I run nvidia-smi only 6 cards are available. When I run lshw -c video I see that there are 2 UNCLAIMED cards. Checked hardware. Reinstalled OS. Installed latest Nvidia drivers. Nothing helps. Any ideas?